# jQuery - Object + nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Trying to get the first cell in a row by using first-child or nth-child, but the syntax isn't playing nice. This is what I'm trying and it isn't working:

```
....
sections[key][2][sections[key][2].length-1] //Table Row
$(sections[key][2][sections[key][2].length-1]+":first-child") //Should be first cell of row
....
```

Instead it returns the entire document...

Comment: what is the value of `sections[key][2][sections[key][2].length-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector:

```
$(sections[key][2][sections[key][2].length-1]+":first-child")
```

is attempting to concatenate a JavaScript object with a string, which will result in (something similar) [`[object HTMLTableRowElement]:first-child`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tG4Sy/1/) which, obviously, is not going to produce a jQuery object, or a DOM node.

Given that (you say) `$(sections[key][2][sections[key][2].length-1]` is the `tr` element (though why you're using that notation within a jQuery selector is a mystery to me), I'd suggest:

```
$(sections[key][2][sections[key][2].length-1]).find('td:first-child');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tG4Sy/2/).

Note the use of the `td` with the `:first-child` pseudo-class, in order to prevent selecting the first-child of all subsequent elements.

However, to get the first cell of all table-rows (using jQuery's more understandable notation) I'd suggest:

```
$('table tr td:first-child')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tG4Sy/3/).

Or, to use `:nth-child()` to get an arbitrarily-numbered `td`:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tG4Sy/4/).

Comment: $(sections[key][2][sections[key][2].length-1]).find('td:first-child');

This worked! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! But, do note, that you seem to be vastly over-complicating your selectors (it might be efficient, and/or *feel* like 'proper JavaScript, but it's going to make future maintenance painful, unless you're commenting a lot).

Comment: I could've got the cell the proper jQuery way if the context was as simple as just trying to get a cell from a table but I have some big functions that go through the table and split it up into sections and there's fugly Javascript arrays and all sorts, I would've given more context but I figured it wasn't necessary for the answer.

In essence, I know the proper way to do it but in this specific case I had no choice but to use the object, but thanks anyway ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return the first child regardless, why don't you do:

```
sections[key][2][sections[key][2].length-1].firstChild
```

Do keep in mind that selecting via jQuery what you can get very easily via DOM is just slowing down your code for no good reason.

Comment: Just gives me "undefined".

Comment: @Jazcash Well in that case the object @ sections[key][2][sections[key][2].length-1] quite simply does't have any children, otherwise at least something would get returned.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
$(sections[key][2][sections[key][2].length-1]+" td:first-child")
```